# How to increase the read operation in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am loading millions of data in mongodb. I have two shards. Currently I'm using 2 indexes. After loading 15 million records in mongodb, I am not satisfied with the reading performance. I gone through that increasing the RAM, will increase the reading performance. But I am confused where to increase the RAM. Is RAM must be increased in shards or in the Query Router to increase the reading performance?

Comment: What's the bottleneck?

Comment: To query 5 lakh documents, it taking 1 minute which is very large. Now my shards is of 6 GB RAM @KarolyHorvath

Comment: OK, but what's the bottleneck?

Comment: I thought the bottleneck could be the RAM

Comment: In the shards. If you are using mongodb it will put as much data as possible inside the RAM while keeping the data on-disk. Reading from the RAM takes far less time than reading from the disk, which needs to seek back and forth over and over at a much slower speed (if it's an HDD) or needs to read large chunks and then chop it down (SSD).

Comment: You've *thought*? Engineers tend to measure.

Comment: I ll measure @KarolyHorvath